# Type name at the end of c++ expression;

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator, typename

I am learning c++ operator overloading, and I have met to this code

```
/*Global overloading*/
void* operator new(size_t size, char c) {
    cout<<"overloaded"<<endl;
    void * ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);

    if(ptr != NULL) {
        *((char*) ptr) = c;
    }

    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    char * c = new('k') char;

    cout<<*c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Specially, is strange for me the name **char** at the end of first line of function main. Please tell me what kind of expression is it, and how to understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 My bad, I noticed he just overloaded the new operator and added a binary parameter. You overloaded the new operator is all with a binary parameter and has a type of char. So instead of `new char("");` which is default, it is now `new ("") char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` is an operator, that can optionally take arguments. Usually this argument will be a pointer to the memory where the object should be constructed (placement new), but in this case, you are defining a `new` operator that takes a `char` as an argument, and proceed to use it in `main` with `'k'` as its argument. The entire expression `new(...)` serves as the operator in this context, and is followed by the type to construct as you are used to. It's really just a variation of `new char` to call the specified overload of `operator new`.

Note that `new(...) type` does not just allocate the memory, it also calls the constructor of `type`, which you cannot modify by overloading. The `operator new()` functions are only used to provide the memory into which to construct the object. With type being `char`, that's not relevant, but with class types it is.

The typical usage is to use an overload that accepts a pointer to some memory, and returns that pointer verbatim (placement new), allowing the calling code to supply its own memory like so:

```
char* incompletelyConstructedArray = new char[allocSize];
elementType* element = new(&incompletelyConstructedArray[elementLocation]) elementType;
```

This constructs a single object of type `elementType` within the memory region allocated above. `std::vector<>` needs to do this under the hood to avoid default constructing objects when it grows its internal memory. But normal user code should be blissfully unaware that `new()` even exists...